# \n from firebase doesn't works

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, newline

I wan't to print a string from firebase with new lines, but "\n" is printed, instead of making a new line.

[image: This is how the string is recorded in firebase]

```
var foo = "Hi \n How \n are \n you?";
console.log('firesbase', article.test, typeof(article.test));
console.log('foo', foo, typeof(foo));
```

This is what I get from console:

```
firesbase Hi \n How \n are \n you? string

foo Hi 
 How 
 are 
 you? string
```

Can someone help me why the string from firebase is not treated the same way, and what I have to do that it does? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know why, but this works:

```
article.text.split('\\n').map((item, key) => {
   return <span key={key}>{item}<br /></span>
}
```

Comment: This works, because you're actually storing `\\n` (with a double backslash) in Firestore. If you were storing a `\n` (escape sequence for a newline), the console would not display it (it simply ignores newlines).